# Typo3 - remove values from facets

Tags: solr, typo3, facet

I'm using typo3 7.6 and solr in my website.

I want to show my facet **state**, but only showing the value **5** of it (hide the rest, the value is from a backend multiselect)

This is my tx_solr.ts

```
plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting.facets.state{
    includeInAvailableFacets = 1
    excludeValues = '1,2,3,4'
}
```

This is one of the data I want to hide

> a:8:{s:6:"hidden";s:0:"";s:4:"link";s:86:"Ouvert";s:3:"url";s:50:"/fr/appels/?tx_solr%5Bfilter%5D%5B0%5D=state%253A1";s:4:"text";s:6:"Ouvert";s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:5:"count";i:19;s:8:"selected";s:1:"0";s:10:"facet_name";s:5:"state";}

So the value is **1**, but it's still showing on my facets. Can't figure out why, I've struggle with this for hours now...

Comment: Usually, TypoScript's comma-separated values aren't quoted, so the first I'd suggest check is `excludeValues = 1,2,3,4`, see [the doc](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/TypoScriptSyntax.html#value-assignment-the-operator)

Comment: Also as mentioned in [solr ext doc](https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/master/en-us/Configuration/Reference/TxSolrSearch.html#faceting-facets-facetname-excludevalues) the correct path is `plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting.facets.[facetName].excludeValues` so if I'm not wrong in your case that should be `plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting.facets.status.excludeValues `

Comment: @biesior also tried without quote, no results

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm working with Typo3 7.6, what you've seen is for the current version of typo3

Comment: What I told you is valid for **all** versions of TYPO3 for last 20+ years...

Comment: So why isn't the path with **status** isn't is the docs ?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the version of the used extension instead of the version of the TYPO3 core. The `excludeValues` is introduced in [`Solr ver. 7.0.0`](https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/master/en-us/Releases/solr-release-7-0.html) which works with [`TYPO3 ver. 8.7.0 - 8.99.99`](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/solr). Most probably you are using `solr 6.5.1` or earlier.

It cannot be mentioned in the documentation of `Solr ver. < 7.0.0` as it doesn't exist there yet which is also described in the [linked documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/master/en-us/Configuration/Reference/TxSolrSearch.html#faceting-facets-facetname-excludevalues).

Finally even when you'll update TYPO3 core and solr ext to the newest versions the valid path to setting this facet [according to the docs](https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/master/en-us/Configuration/Reference/TxSolrSearch.html#faceting-facets-facetname-excludevalues) should be like:

```
plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting.facets.status.excludeValues = 1,2,3
```